# Bootstrap 5 Nav bar padding removal

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, blazor, bootstrap-5

I've actually got two questions with the NavBar. First I'm trying to figure out a way to get rid of all the padding/margin around the NavBar Item links. I have a left border and a background hoover color that I'm trying to get to expand the height of the NavBar. I've tried a handful of things below but can't seem to find a way to get rid of the padding. Picture below.

Second, if have a menu item with a drop down menu that is getting cut off because the text is wide and it's overflowing the browser border. Is there a way to keep it from overflowing the border?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Users Admin</a>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Search</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown link
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>


.navbar {
    background-color: #0078d2;
    border-color: #0065b1;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-text,
.navbar-brand,
.navbar-link,
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: white !important;
}

.navbar-nav > .active {
    color: red !important;
}

/*.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}*/

.navbar-default, 
.navbar-nav > li {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-default,
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default,
.navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #0065B1;
    /*color: #E2E3E5 !important;*/
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
    border-left: .1rem solid #ccc;
}
```

[image]

***UPDATE 1***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The padding on the links is from the `nav-link` and `navbar-expand-lg` classes

```
.nav-link {
    padding: var(--bs-nav-link-padding-y) var(--bs-nav-link-padding-x);
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: var(--bs-navbar-nav-link-padding-x);
    padding-left: var(--bs-navbar-nav-link-padding-x);
  }
}
```

This can be easily overruled in your stylesheet with the [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important) flag

```
.nav-link {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Or you can add the appropriate [padding class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding) such as `p-0` to each link. Breakpoint classes can also be used.

```
<a class="nav-link p-0" href="#">
```

---

The dropdown menu uses absolute positioning with `left: 0`, which aligns the menu flush to the left of the dropdown link. You can change the [menu alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment) to the right side by adding the `dropdown-menu-end` class.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
```

---

I also optimized your CSS selectors and removed the ineffective margin declarations.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #0078d2;
  border-color: #0065b1;
}

.navbar-brand,
.navbar-link,
.nav-link {
  color: white !important;
}

.active {
  color: red !important;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus {
  background-color: #0065B1;
  /* color: #E2E3E5 !important; */
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: .5em 0 !important;
  border-left: .1rem solid #ccc !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Users Admin</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Search</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The menu change you mentioned worked perfectly. However, I'm still struggling with the menu. I updated my CSS with some of your suggestions but still not getting it. I'm still trying to play around with things but with changes to the but it still seems like there is an inner padding on the NavBar. I created a new project, added your CSS and HTML and got the same results as my changes. I added another screen shot to my original post. I'm trying to get rid of the padding at the top and bottom of the <li> and make the <li> border and color fill the menu vertically.

Comment: @Caverman The space is due to padding on `navbar` as well as the height of `navbar-brand`. This uses flexbox, so the items have the same height, and the links are aligned in the center. I edited the answer to add .5em top/bottom padding to `nav-link` to match the height.